# Should not import the named export 'name' (imported as 'packageName') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-scripts

Getting this error on upgrading react-scripts from 3.4.1 to ^5.0.0. I have checked in code, import and export statements seems fine and not importing package.json in any file,  but could not able to build it.

```
Should not import the named export 'name' (imported as 'packageName') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)
```

How to debug in which file it has errors. Any idea/suggestions to resolve it?
I would appreciate your answers!

Comment: Use default export from package instead of named export version

Answer (score 1):

The problem is it is trying to find a default export for "name" in your JSON file.
For this use:

1. import (jsonfilename ) from '../(filename).json'

Now you will be able to access the data deconstructing

2. const {any value you want to access from the JSON file} = (JSON file name).json; //keep the rest of the code the same
   See the image if you didn't understand.

[image]

Now your problem must be Solved.
Thanks.
#HappyCoding

Comment: this is not the issue, Im experiencing the same error with `import { myFunctionName } from '../my-file'`

Comment: My latest compile had 450 errors like this, all for 
 'jsxDEV' (imported as '_jsxDEV')  Must be dependency versions or something.